# How to Assign values to Expression tree parameters and evaluate

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'm hoping some kind soul here might be able to help me with this. Essentially, I've got a random function represented as an expression tree in C#. I would like for it to consist of variables, and for me to be able to evaluate it based on the values I assign the variables. So, in its simplest form, the tree might look like:

```
ParameterExpression a = Expression.Variable(typeof(double), "a");
ParameterExpression b = Expression.Variable(typeof(double), "b");
Expression function = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Subtract, a, b);
```

so that the function looks like `(a - b)`. I then wish to evaluate this, which I can do as:

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<double, double, double>>(function, a, b).Compile()(5.0, 3.0);
```

The problems I have are:

1. The function is randomly generated, so I do not know how many variables it has. I only have a list of possible variables
2. I do not know in what order the variables are used

So is there a way I can declare, much like normal code, `a = 4` and `b = 2` and then compile the function based on those declarations?

If not, then what other alternatives are there? So far I have:

- Loop through the tree (using `ExpressionVisitor`) and replace, say `a` with just `Expression.Constant(4.0)`
- Go down the route of:

  ```
  ParameterExpression variableExpr = Expression.Variable(typeof(double), "a");
  Expression assignExpr = Expression.Assign(variableExpr,Expression.Constant(4.0));
  Expression a = Expression.Block(new ParameterExpression[] { variableExpr }, assignExpr);
  [...]
  Expression.Lambda<Func<double>>(function).Compile()();
  ```

  but I would like to try and avoid adding block segments to the function if possible.

Any help and pointers would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Can you show an example of some input that will drive the creation of the expression tree?

Comment: Seems like classic http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Why not using a library which already resolve arithmetic expression?

Answer (score 1):

> I do not know how many variables it has.

You have the list of all possible variables. Because of that, I think the simplest solution would be to always assume all variables are used. So, you generate a lambda that has all the variables as parameters and then call it while passing values to all parameters.

> I do not know in what order the variables are used

I don't see how does that matter. The order of parameters when declaring the function and when calling the function have to match, but you control both, so that shouldn't be a problem.